# Count Observations Meeting Certain Criteria by Group R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I need some help counting observations meeting certain criteria by group. I first want the number of employees by location as a column. Then I would like to retrieve the number of employees that have worked more than 40 hours (by location) and summarize that into a column. I assume there is an easy way to do it with dplyr or base R but I'm stumped. My data is below.

```
name       hours_worked  location
Bob        55            IL
Nick       25            IL 
Sally      30            IL
Patricia   50            WI
Tim        35            WI
Liz        42            OH
Brad       60            OH
Sam        48            OH
```

Ideal output would be something like:

```
location   headcount   over_40 
IL            3          1
WI            2          1
OH            3          3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by operation - grouped by 'location' get the number of rows (`n()`) for headcount and the `sum` of logical vector to get the count of 'over_40'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(location) %>% 
   summarise(headcount = n(), over_40 = sum(hours_worked > 40))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  location headcount over_40
  <chr>        <int>   <int>
1 IL               3       1
2 OH               3       3
3 WI               2       1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Bob", "Nick", "Sally", "Patricia", "Tim", 
"Liz", "Brad", "Sam"), hours_worked = c(55L, 25L, 30L, 50L, 35L, 
42L, 60L, 48L), location = c("IL", "IL", "IL", "WI", "WI", "OH", 
"OH", "OH")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```